# ¿Es posible crear un input que se auto-ajuste a su contenido?

Tags: html, css

Por diseño requiero que un `input` se vaya auto-ajustando de acuerdo al tamaño del texto que se introduce, en la siguiente imagen muestro lo que requiero, la linea debe ir pegada al final del texto "titulo", pero si ponen una cadena mas larga, que el `input` se vaya haciendo mas grande para ir tapando la linea y en caso contrario el `input` se ajuste al tamaño de la cadena para que la linea de atrás esté pegada al titulo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 7):

El efecto del `input` que se ajusta a su contenido lo podrías simular fácilmente usando dos `div`.

El `div` externo actuaría como contenedor y sería el que estableciera la anchura mínima que tendrá el input simulado. Además, deberás usar la propiedad `display: inline-block` para que el contenedor se ajuste a su contenido.

Posteriormente, el `div` que actuará de `input` deberá de utilizar la propiedad `contenteditable="true"` para que su contenido sea editable. Deberás utilizar la propiedad `width: 100%` para que se ajuste al 100% de la anchura del contenedor.

Ejemplo:

```css
#contenedor{
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px;
}

#texto{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
    <div id="texto" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

Sin embargo, como supongo que querrás utilizar el valor que tenga este input simulado (que en realidad es un `div`) al enviar los datos a través del formulario, lo que puedes realizar es crear un `input` oculto y asignarle el valor del input simulado a este `input` oculto mediante `Javascript`.

El código, dentro de un formulario y junto con el `Javascript` correspondiente, quedaría algo así como:

```js
document.forms["formulario"].onsubmit = function(){
    var texto = document.getElementById("tituloOculto").value = document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML;
    alert(texto);
}
```

```css
#contenedor{
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px;
}

#texto{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario" action="tuarchivo.php" method="post">
  <div id="contenedor">
    <div id="texto" contenteditable="true"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="titulo" id="tituloOculto" />
  <button type="submit">Agregar Nuevo</button>
</form>
```

donde `tuarchivo.php` será el documento PHP en el que recuperes los datos del formulario. Al asignarle los datos al `input` con la propiedad `name` y siendo `titulo` el valor de dicha propiedad, podrás recuperar el dato para el título desde tu PHP así:

```
$_POST["titulo"];
```

ya que previamente le has asignado el valor del texto del input simulado mediante `Javascript` al enviar el formulario.

**Nota:** En el segundo ejemplo no se mostrará el `alert` ya que el sistema bloquea el envío del formulario, supongo que por temas de seguridad y porque el fichero no existe. **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3rowyoyf/1/)** sin embargo si que te deja enviar el formulario y mostrar la alerta aunque luego te muestre un error como que, evidentemente, no puede enviar nada a ese fichero ya que no lo encuentra.

Como puedes observar, puedes simular el efecto de un `input` que se ajuste a su contenido simplemente con CSS. Luego para poder enviarlo a través del formulario solo necesitarás un `input` oculto adicional y un par de líneas de `Javascript`.

Answer (score 2):

Si es posible usando `jQuery`, he reformado un poco el código de [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100770/auto-scaling-inputtype-text-to-width-of-value) respuesta:

```js
function resizeInput() {
  
  var valueLength = $(this).prop('value').length;
  
    // Para que no arroje error si el input se vacía
    if (valueLength > 0) {
      
      $(this).prop('size', valueLength);
    }
}

$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', resizeInput).each(resizeInput);
```

```css
input[type="text"] {  
  min-width: 100px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="El input se alarga ahora automáticamente" />
```

Comment: Disculpa la ignorancia la priemra parte del codigo lo pongo en una etiqueta script tipo javascript y el segundo en una etiqueta de script tipo css?

Comment: @AlbertoRojas - El css es solo para que no se colapse en la demo si alguien borra el contenido... pero supongo que tendrás ya estilos y tal... como veo en la imagen... y el primer código lo puedes poner dentro de una etiqueta `<script>` o quizás mejor en tu fichero de javascript... si necesitas ayuda me dices